# How to convert an int[] into an List<Integer> in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, list, integer

It seems like a simple matter; I have an `int[]` that I prepopulate at initialization, then I want to convert it to a `List<Integer>`, but this doesn't work:

```
int[] ACTIVITIES = {0,1,2};
List<Integer> acta = Arrays.asList(ACTIVITIES);
```

`Arrays.asList()` wants to make a `List<int[]>` instead, and I don't understand why.  How do I make a `List<Integer>` out of an `int[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change from `int` to `Integer`

```
Integer[] ACTIVITIES = {0,1,2};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need an array at all:

```
List<Integer> acta = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Sorry, this was a simplified example; I am pulling several arrays from another class, and I want to concatenate them as a single list.  I was just wondering why int[] didn't work, and I still don't understand the difference between int and Integer, but at least it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> acta = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<ACTIVITIES.Length;i++){
      acta.Add(ACTIVITIES[i]);
}
```

this is sample code,maybe the keywords different from that i wrote but the solution is like this.